# A way to prevent special entity to be resolved in xslfo

Tags: xml, xslt, special-characters, xsl-fo

I have the following simple xslt code:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$shape">&#9658;</xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="self::node()" mode="default"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

My issue is in the "when" branch above, I want to render an arrow in the final pdf, so I specified the special entity there. However, it is already rendered as an arrow in the fo file, so the arrow won't come through in the final pdf.

What I want now is to keep the ► shown as text in the fo too instead of being resolved to an arrow in the fo.

Could any experts help on how to prevent xslt or xsl-fo to resolve special entities?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...it is already rendered as an arrow in the fo file, so the arrow won't come through in the final pdf.

This sounds very strange. From an XML point of view, the `&#9658;` character reference is exactly the same as the ► character. It should not matter which of these representations is used in the FO file.

A more likely cause of the problem is that the arrow glyph is missing in the font used in the PDF file.